# UISearchBar How To Dismiss Keyboard and Select Item

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

For various reasons, I am using UISearchBar by itself to filter contents of a UITableView. The filtering works great. However, it requires two taps to select something. The first tap dismisses the keyboard and then the second selects an item in the UITableView. Is there a way I can have a single tap dismiss the keyboard and select an item?

Answer (score 0):

For `UITableView` specifically you can use:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    superview?.endEditing(true)
}
```

This will end editing when the table view is dragged.

In a more general sense, the `endEditing(Bool)` function, when called on a `UIView`, looks through the views entire sub hierarchy and if an editing text element is found will resign it. The parameter is to determine whether the view should be asked to resign as first responder or simply be forced to resign as first responder.

As per documentation: "This method looks at the current view and its subview hierarchy for the text field that is currently the first responder. If it finds one, it asks that text field to resign as first responder. If the force parameter is set to true, the text field is never even asked; it is forced to resign."

This means that you can call `endEditing(true)` directly within `didSelectItemAt`, just make sure you call it on a view that has the search bar as a subview. Or just call it on the search bar itself.